# Why is my BaseController.User value == null when the area controller loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing an Asp.Net core application and I have the user authenticate with Google prior to gaining navigation access.  When the user navigates to my "WorldBuilder" area and hits the WorldController, the BaseController.User object is null.  This is the only area/controller I have set up so far.

The user is valid when the log in, as I can iterate over the Claims associated with the user.  I am using the default Asp.Net core google authentication, so the user just receives a button on the login page directing them to authenticate with Google.

```
[Authorize]
[Area("WorldBuilder")]
public class WorldController : Controller
{
    private string _userId;
    private IWorldService _worldService;
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public WorldController(IWorldService worldService, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        if (User != null) /* The user object is found to be null here. */
        {
            var userIdNameClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (userIdNameClaim != null)
            {
                _userId = userIdNameClaim.Value;
            }
        }
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _worldService = worldService;
    }
```

I would expect that since the areas are part of the same application that the authenticated user information would be passed between areas, however that does not appear to be the case.  The BaseController.User object is null

Comment: It is because you are trying to access the `User` in the constructor, and this is called before any authorization takes place.  It's not clear in your code why you'd need the user at this point - if you require it in an `Action`, then the `User` will have been initiated at this point.

Comment: If the `User` is null in the ctor then the `HttpContext` must not have been set by the framework at that point. You have no control over that. Why not extract your id-getting logic onto an extension method on `ClaimsPrincipal` and then just replace usage of `_userId` with e.g. `User.GetId()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should only access the `User` property (and others such as `HttpContext`) from within actions of your controller. The controller is constructed before authentication and authorization have been performed, hence the properties are null.

If you need general access to the User ID, you could create a property on the controller where you retrieve the User ID from the user object and use that property from your actions. You can even move this property to a base class and use that class as base controller to have access to the property from each controller.

For example:

```cs
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if (User != null) /* The user object is found to be null here. */
            {
                var userIdNameClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                if (userIdNameClaim != null)
                {
                    return userIdNameClaim.Value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And your specific controller:

```cs
public class WorldController : ControllerBase
{

    // Contructor, etc...

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       var userId = UserId;

       // Do something with userId (or use UserId directly)
    }

}
```

Comment: The prevailing advice is "Do that in the action, not the constructor" so I'll go that route. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use **HttpContextAccessor** to pass the **HttpContext** down the line to **Areas, Repositories** etc

More about how to use **HttpContextAccessor** and set it up using **Depenedency injection** here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components